# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status 23:05:22 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 441ms)

Tags: compilation

when i'm trying to build my project, the console showing that 1 error is exist. but i don't know what is the error is. can anyone help me ?

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\basics1.o" "..\\src\\basics1.c" 
gcc -o basics1.exe "src\\basics1.o" 
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file basics1.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

23:05:22 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 441ms)
```

Comment: Either `basics1.exe` is running right now (you have to close it before you can overwrite ist) or you are trying to write into a directory you don't have write access to (for instance something inside `Program Files`).

Comment: Most probable reason: Your program is already running. Other possible reason: You don't have write-access to the directory where the `basics1.exe` is being written.